# Python search column of text and return if there are any matching keywords from a list of words

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns, message_id and msg_lower. I also have a list of keywords called terms. My goal is to search the msg_lower field for any words that are in the terms list. If they match, I would like to return a tuple that contains the message_id and keyword.

the data looks like this:

```sh
|message_id|msg_lower                      |
|1116193453|text here that means something |
|9023746237|more text there meaning nothing|
```

```py
terms = [text, nothing, there meaning]
```

Terms can be longer than one word as well

and for the given example i would like to return:

```sh
[(1116193453, text),(9023746237,text),(9023746237,nothing),(9023746237,there meaning)]
```

Ideally I would like to do this as efficiently as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip both columns for possible loop by tuples, loop by terms and test is membership in splitted values:

```
terms = ['text', 'nothing']
a = [(x,i) for x, y in zip(df['message_id'],df['msg_lower']) for i in terms if i in y.split()]
print (a)
[(1116193453, 'text'), (9023746237, 'text'), (9023746237, 'nothing')]
```

EDIT:

```
terms = ['text', 'nothing', 'there meaning']

a = [(x, i) for x, y in zip(df['message_id'],df['msg_lower']) for i in terms if i in y]
print (a)
[(1116193453, 'text'), (9023746237, 'text'), 
 (9023746237, 'nothing'), (9023746237, 'there meaning')]
```

Another idea is use `findall` with word boundaries for extract values:

```
a = [(x, i) for x, y in zip(df['message_id'],df['msg_lower']) 
            for i in terms if re.findall(r"\b{}\b".format(i), y)]
```

Comment: This works for all the terms that are single words, but I edited my question, the keywords can be longer than just one word

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
list(df.apply(lambda x: [(i, x['message_id']) for i in re.findall('|'.join(terms),x['msg_lower'])], axis=1).apply(pd.Series).stack())
```

**Output**

```
[('text', 1116193453), ('text', 9023746237), ('nothing', 9023746237)]
```

Comment: Edited my question, the terms can actually be longer than just one word

Answer (score 0):

If your keywords are just words (don't contain spaces), you could use sets. I don't know exactly how your data is stored, with 2-dimensional arrays it could work like this:

```
data = [["1116193453", "text here that means something"],
        ["9023746237", "more text there meaning nothing"]]
terms = {"text", "nothing"}

matches = []
for row in data:
    for word in set(row[1].split()) & terms:
        matches.append((row[0], word))

print(matches)
# [('1116193453', 'text'), ('9023746237', 'text'), ('9023746237', 'nothing')]
```

Comment: What if they do contain spaces?